# pointer to char array seg fault on strcpy , but work with equal sign

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

I would like to know why does the pointer of char array can get affected a value with the equals sign as it would normally have to be string copied ? Why can I print the content of anArray[0].ptr[0] as a %s string ?

Is there a way to copy the whole string to the structure in anArray[0] and keeping it even if hello is freed ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct arrayOf {
  int line;
  int col;
  char ** ptr;
}

int main(void){

 char * hello = "Hello";

 struct arrayOf anArray[5];
 anArray[0].ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
 anArray[0].ptr[0] = malloc(100*sizeof(char));

 anArray[0].ptr[0] = hello; //work
 strcpy(anArray[0].ptr[0], hello); //seg fault

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting anArray[0].ptr[0] with the assignment (causing a memory leak), so anArray[0].ptr[0] is no longer pointing to the allocated memory.

```
strcpy(anArray[0].ptr[0], hello); //copied hello to anArray[0].ptr[0]
anArray[0].ptr[0] = hello; //cause a memory leak and anArray[0].ptr[0] points to unwritable memory(probably)
```

Comment: Actually, the equals does not yield seg fault, the strcpy does.

Comment: The equal changes where `anArray[0].ptr[0]` points to so when you try to use `strcpy` on it you get the segfault

Comment: It crashes even if the expression with the equal is removed. only leaving strcpy as you see it